# Using keyboard to trigger modal in addition to mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery

hoping someone could help out with this. would like to trigger the [Frames modal component](https://pastebin.com/rgfecYAt)
not only by mouse click but also keyboard key, such as '/'.

```
Mousetrap.bind("/", function () {
jQuery(".trigger--modal").trigger("click");
});
```

tried the above using [mousetrap](https://craig.is/killing/mice) with no luck. perhaps there's also a more straight forward way to trigger the modal directly. also, perhaps a way to use the [bricks builder](https://bricksbuilder.io/) native keyboard functions on the frontend instead of a separate library (although it's fairly robust).

thanks!